# mvc 4 How to populate dropdownlist from collection in model on create page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I am sure this is a simple thing that I am missing.  I was trying to add a dropdownlist to the Create.cshtml with the purpose of  populating the list from a database. 
For the experiment I mucked up the following:
two classes that correspond to database tables that have values.

```
namespace MvcTestApplication.Models
{
public class Complaints
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string User { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public string  Nature { get; set; }
    public string Month { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }
    public string Account { get; set; }
    public string Employee { get; set; }
    public string Manager { get; set; }
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }
    public int CompanyNumID { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public int ClientID { get; set; }
    public int ClientCodeID { get; set; }
    public string Source { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Company> Companies{ get; set; }
}
namespace MvcTestApplication.Models
{
public class Company
{
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public bool enabled { get; set; }

}
}
```

then a DAL

```
namespace MvcTestApplication.DAL
{

public class ComplaintDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Complaints> Complaints { get; set; }

}
```

On the create.cshtml page I just want to be able to populate a dropdownlist with the companies (many more dropdownlists after I get this working) but so far I always get a null reference whenever I try. On the  create actionresult I tried passing a new Complaints model, just the complaints model, I am missing how to make the companies collection be populated.

```
 <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReleaseDate, new { id = "release_date" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Source)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Source)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Source)
    </div>
  <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CompanyID)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CompanyID , new SelectList(Model.Companies , "CompanyID", "CompanyName"), "-- Select Company--")

        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CompanyID)
    </div>
```

Comment: I am doing code first for the tables and I have verified that there is data there. The index page lists the sample complaints I seeded the table with correctly.

Comment: I guess I should add that this would be good to have in Edit mode as well (the dropdowns)

Comment: I think I got it to work:
     public ActionResult Create()
        {
            List<Company> comps = db.Companies.ToList();
            return View(new Complaints { Nature = "test this",   Source = "Email", ReleaseDate = DateTime.Now, Companies = comps  });
         
            //return View();
        }

Comment: and now I am trying to work on how to display the value of the companyid (companyname) in the index view.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to build a template for your complex object type Complaints. Something like this should get you started to define a custom editor template for Complaints. This will automatically be rendered for each element in the Complaints collection.

You need to store it in ~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Complaints.cshtml:

```
@model Complaints

<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.id): 
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.id)

    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Nature): 
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Nature)

    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ReleaseDate): 
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.ReleaseDate)

    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Source): 
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Source)

    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Status): 
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Status)
</div>
```

To us, simply write:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Complaints)
```